# Calculated column hyperlink generated not displaying text

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, sharepoint-calendar, 2019

I have a SharePoint on-premises calendar list created. need a hyperlink column in event view form to download ics file from a hyperlink.

The download link gets created and works fine but i need to hide the link and display a text instead.

```
="http://{site url}/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List={LIST_GUID}&CacheControl=1&ID="&ID&"&Using=event.ics"
```

The above when added to calculated column of calendar list works fine. But it displays the entire url.

The data type returned from this formula is: Single line of text

Need to change display text as "click to download ics file".

Please suggest any ways to achieve this.

when searched online ,
SharePoint Server 2013 and SharePoint Server 2016
The June 2017 PU and subsequent PUs will include a new web application setting that's called CustomMarkupInCalculatedFieldDisabled. This setting lets an on-premises administrator determine whether execution of custom markup in calculated fields in a given web application is blocked.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using, 2016?

Comment: sharepoint onpremise 2019

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula:

```
"<a href='http://{site url}/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List={LIST_GUID}&CacheControl=1&ID="&ID&"&Using=event.ics'>click to download ics file</a>"
```

OR

```
=CONCATENATE(
    "<a href='http://{site url}/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List={LIST_GUID}&CacheControl=1&ID=",
    [ID],
    "&Using=event.ics'>click to download ics file</a>"
)
```

**Documentation**: [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

---

**Note**: *Some users have added HTML markup or script elements to calculated fields. This is an undocumented use of the feature, and we will block the execution of custom markup in calculated fields in SharePoint Online from June 13, 2017 onwards. The June 2017 Public Update (PU) and later PUs will make blocking a configurable option for on-premises use in SharePoint Server 2016 and SharePoint Server 2013.*

**Source**: [Handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields-a3db28e4-747c-437e-b085-8f795b722a8c)

So, HTML markup may not work in calculated columns.

Comment: no this didnt work. tried it in different way using javascript in script editor